# Creating a 2D texture array for depth view

Tags: c++, directx, directx11, shadows, depth-buffer

Following my question [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/66228/34077), I decided to create an 2D texture array for all of my depth screen texture so that I can use them for shadows for all my lights.

I'm having an issue setting it up, I'm getting an `E_INVALIDARG` when I try to create it.

This code is what I use to create the 2D array Texture

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC sTexDesc;
sTexDesc.Width = this->Width;  // 1024
sTexDesc.Height = this->Height;// 1024
sTexDesc.MipLevels = 0;
sTexDesc.ArraySize = arraySize; // The value is 25 here
sTexDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS;
sTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
sTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
sTexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
sTexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
sTexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
sTexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

HRESULT hr = pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&sTexDesc, NULL, &(this->shadowTexture));
if(FAILED(hr))
    throw std::exception("Failed at creating texture array for shadows");
```

This is the code that I use to create the depth view

```
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC dsvDesc;
ZeroMemory(&dsvDesc, sizeof(dsvDesc));
dsvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
dsvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DARRAY;
dsvDesc.Texture2DArray.ArraySize = arraySize; // The value is 25 here
dsvDesc.Texture2DArray.FirstArraySlice = index;
HRESULT hr = pd3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(shadowTexture, &dsvDesc, &pDepthMapDSV);
if(FAILED(hr)){ throw std::exception("Error creating 2d texture for shadow"); }
```

`CreateDepthStencilView` will return `OK` for the first texture but it  crashes for the second.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the issue was.

```
dsvDesc.Texture2DArray.ArraySize = arraySize; // The value is 25 here
```

I thought that it wanted to know the full size of the array, but as I read the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it is actually the number of texture to use and so that value should be set to 1.